# Passing ioctl codes from Kernel module to Userspace program

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, ioctl

*ioctl* codes in Kernel modules are usually defined as macros inside *.c* or *.h* file, i.e.:

```
#define DRV_CTL_RESET          _IO(DRV_MAGIC, 0x01)
#define DRV_CTL_DSP_TO         _IO(DRV_MAGIC, 0x02)
```

and the usage in Userspace program is:

```
ioctl(drv_fd, DRV_CTL_DSP_TO, (unsigned long)tmo);
```

Everything is fine, but..

**The problem is:** what are good practices of synchronizing *ioctl* codes between Kernel and Userspace?

My current solution is to auto-generate an API header file from the source of Kernel module and include it in the Userspace program. But I hope, maybe there is a more convenient way.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the ioctl codes in a .h file, and use the same .h from kernel space and userspace. What could be more convenient than that? ;)

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. But to have *_IO* macros defined, few other Kernel headers must be included. That looks kind of excessive when only few numbers are needed.

Comment: _IO macros are defined in <asm/generic.h> which should be present on any linux system with development headers installed. These headers - in /usr/include/{asm-generic,linux} - are always exported to userspace.

Comment: I know that and it works. But I'm writing a library for an embedded system and want as few dependencies from Kernel as possible. So my goal is to have raw numbers in Userspace, much like *#define DRV_CTL_RESET 0x150* (just a random number for the sake of clarity).

Comment: @KBart When the ioctls were first designed the numbers were supposed to embed a certain amount of magic, and the macros exist because that magic might change from time to time. In reality this is all ancient history, but the legacy is that you really should define them using the macros, meaning you need to depend on the kernel headers. Even if you're developing for an embedded platform you only need to headers on the machine where you're compiling, not the embedded platform that you're deploying to.

Comment: So I assume the answer is no, there are no better ways.. Thank you both for the answers.